# Manage root privileges for users on Red Hat Azure VM

Tags: rhel, privileges

We have set up a Red Hat VM on Azure, but we are unsure how we could deal with user privileges. We want to use the VM to test software in a Linux environment as opposed to the Windows workstations that we have.

We would like to have two user groups:

1) admin Account

2) user Accounts: They need to be able to install packages via yum, but should not be able to change system relevant information (by accident) like ssh-keys, other users' passwords etc. However, from this [yum install in user home for non-admins](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/61283/yum-install-in-user-home-for-non-admins) I understood that sudo privileges are necessary to do yum installs.

How could we achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can configure `sudo` in a very fine grain way:

You can tell it to allow user-a to run program-b. You can tell it if a password is needed to do this. Adding a user to group `sudo`, gives that user permission to do anything with `sudo` if they provide a password. But if you edit the `/etc/sudoers` then you can provide this fine grained permission.

Read:

- `man sudoers`
- `man visudo` — for how to edit the sudo file, on a live system, without accidentally locking yourself out.

Comment: Thanks! I was not aware of the possibilities of sudo. So I created a new group `newgroup` and assigned my team members to it. If I put `%newgroup ALL=(root) /usr/bin/yum` in /etc/sudoers, members will only be able to execute yum, right? But yum changes files in some other folders outside `$HOME`, for which the group should not have write privileges. Is this not conflicting?

Comment: Yes yum will write to system directories. Therefore you should check that it can not be subverted (could a user install something that they could use to escalate privileges. Does it have config options, that can be used to escalate privileges.)