# how to check whether some dependencies are lack before a rpm package is installed by a non-root user

Tags: centos, rpm, dependencies, non-root-user

I am a non-root user on a shared centos7 server host.I try to install some softwares on this machine according to the method in the [link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/61295/556700).  How can I check whether some dependencies are lack before installation according to the method in above link.

Answer (score 3):

```bash
rpm -ivh 1.rpm 2.rpm 3.rpm
```

Will report all the missing dependencies. If everything is satisfied it will complain about missing root privileges.

Comment: I tried this command'rpm -ivh git-2.39.0-2.1.src.rpm' to install package `git-2.39.0-2.1.src.rpm`. However, the output is:      warning: git-2.39.0-2.1.src.rpm: Header V3 RSA/SHA256 Signature, key ID 3dbdc284: NOKEY \\
Updating / installing... \\
   1:git-2.39.0-2.1                   ################################# [100%]\\ It didn't point out any packages missing or missing root privileges.

Comment: src.rpm is a **source** package which needs to be rebuilt (compiled). It will "install" because it will be actually just unpacked into `~/rpmbuild`.

Comment: yep, and as source package, it has no dependencies – building it has. But that's a different story